# Why rasa init is not getting executed?

Tags: python-3.x, rasa

I have installed rasa using the below commands on my `Windows 10`.

```
d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>python -m venv ./venv
d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>.\venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>pip3 install -U --user pip
(venv) d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
(venv) d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>pip3 install rasa
```

After the above, I have run

```
(venv) d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>rasa init
```

for which I am getting the message:

> 'rasa' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

I tried to rerun the `pip3 install rasa`, which shows that all requirements are satisfied. Why is that `rasa init` is not getting executed? What shall be done? Appreciate inputs.

```
(venv) d:\Learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy>pip3 install rasa

Requirement already satisfied: rasa in d:\learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy\venv\lib\site-packages (0.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy\venv\lib\site-packages (from rasa) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in d:\learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa) (2.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in d:\learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in d:\learning\vs_rasa_4_beg_udemy\venv\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa) (3.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the Python version you're using matches the [rasa requirements](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation/environment-set-up) (currently only Python `3.6`, `3.7` and `3.8` are supported)

EDIT: As of April 2023,

> Currently, rasa supports the following Python versions: 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. Note that Python 3.10 is only supported for versions 3.4.x and upwards. Additionally, rasa installation on Apple Silicon with Python 3.10 is not functional in 3.4.x but will be supported starting from 3.5.x.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to update on my question. I have uninstalled lots of stuff including Python.3.10 and installed 3.8 (though initially just installing the Python 3.8 was not working). From then, it started working.